# Google Tasks API "login required" after GET request

Tags: java, google-api, google-oauth, google-tasks

I want to implement a simple task editor on my PC that edits google tasks, creates, reads, etc. I followed the Authetification by Google, and I can see the tasklists I created (I also got the security alert), but I cannot send GET requests without getting a 401 code and the message "Login required".

I have authenticated myself and given my application access already. I tried to use the API explorer by google, ant that worked, but for some reason every GET I send from my application is met with 401 "Login Required"

```java
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("GET https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/lists/{MY_LSIT_ID}/tasks?key={YOUR_API_KEY}"); // Obviously with the actual values
```

I expected to view all the tasks in that taskList as a JSON, but the output JSON I get is:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if the API key alone is enough according to this docs: https://developers.google.com/tasks/auth. You may also need to provide a OAuth token.

Comment: But if that's the case why can I see the lists I've created? Shouldnt that be locked as well since I wouldn't be "properly" Authenticated